# MySQL remote access, cannot expose port

Tags: mysql

As the title says, im trying to access MySQL on my EC2 AWS instance but cannot get it to expose the 3306 port.

My my.cnf file looks like so

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
bind-address=0.0.0.0
# skip-networking

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

*This is not an issue with my security rules on AWS* , running:

```
lsof -n | grep LISTEN
```

Only lists other known processes that are listening to their corresponding ports succesfully.

---

MORE INFO

```
 Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.41                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.41                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux
```

Comment: How do you tell it isn't exposed?

Comment: @emix I would expect mysql is exposing the port the same way all other processes do. My node server listening to 8080 is listed when i execute `lsof -n | grep LISTEN` but there's no process listening to anything like 3306 or looking like mysql. 

in fact since this is a new ec2 instance, my node process is the only one listening to anything so its pretty clear

Comment: Did you try to connect anyway?

Comment: @emix i didnt manage to connect no but there could be multiple reasons this is happening from user access rights to anything related to AWS so i wanted to make sure the process is listening first. you know, troubleshoot it :/

Comment: Try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/782118/mysql-5-7-bind-address-doesnt-work). You are not correct. If you get a permission issue the port is exposed and mysql is working correctly, it's just you who did not authenticate with valid credentials.

Comment: @emix i wonder why it is that im not seing the port when using lsof though, shouldnt it be there? another thing,is that there is no /etc/mysql/.. on my setup, only /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Stack overflow generated this: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181441/discussion-between-george-avgoustis-and-emix).

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis Are you executing lsof as root, or perhaps as ec2-user? Maybe try sudo lsof -n | grep LISTEN ... if you execute lsof as a non-root user, you'll only get info about processes that your non-privileged user owns.

Comment: @dossy very rookie mistake, you are absolutely right..

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis so, `sudo lsof -n | grep LISTEN` shows MySQL listening on a port, as expected?  And you still can't connect?  My guess is that you're connecting with incorrect credentials and/or you have insufficient privileges `GRANT`ed -- assuming you are actually correct that this isn't a AWS EC2 Security Group restriction issue to begin with.